# Attach element position to another that has dynamic height WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize

I have two elements inside a `Grid`, the first one has a dynamic height and the second has a fixed height. When the user resizes the window the first element is supposed to grow bigger until the scrollbar does not show. Here's the code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <!-- MORE STUFF HERE -->
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

And when it's small looks like this:
[image]

When it's big it looks like this:
[image]

How can I attached the `Button` the bottom of the first element, or make the first element stop growing after the content is displayed?

Comment: The solution is @Clemens answer. Regarding your answer, the button height is inherited by the `RowDefinition`, in this case 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Grid's VerticalAlignment to `Top` instead of `Stretch`:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: And you're correct! It's the little things that really bother... thank you for the help.